# Android App not running on any device

Tags: android

I'm having trouble running ANY app on both an emulator and a device. Just running the simple "Hello World" app is not working. The app gets installed on the emulator but never executes. I can find it when I go Menu -> Manage Apps but the only thing I can do from there is uninstall it. It seems there is a setting that is not forcing it to run automatically.

Also, something that was weird was my computer would never let me install the new updates. It would just say "Downloading ....." but nothing ever happened. I fixed the problem by going into Safe Mode with Networking but I can still not run any app. Any ideas???

Here is what it says when I go to Run as -> Android App

```
[2012-08-31 08:17:52 - at] New emulator found: emulator-5554 
[2012-08-31 08:17:52 - at]   Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched... [2012-08-31 08:19:13 - at] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554' 
[2012-08-31 08:19:13 - at] Uploading at.apk onto device 'emulator-5554' 
[2012-08-31 08:19:13 - at] Installing at.apk... 
[2012-08-31 08:20:03 - at] Success! 
[2012-08-31 08:20:03 - at] \at\bin\at.apk installed on device 
[2012-08-31 08:20:03 - at] Done!
```

Here is my Manifest File:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="c.panic"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="parent" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You might not be setting an activity as Main Launcher, if there is no Main Launcher the app can't be started see @SpK answer and check if you have a Main Launcher activity setted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to change your main activity's `<intent-filter>` tag filter in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<application android:name="......"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name=".yourActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Means, you've to change your activity's `<action>` and `<category>`

**Edit**

Just change like below in your manifest file. It will launch your application.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="parent" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thank you so much been frustrated for a few days now.