# Unable to find android app in emulator

Tags: android, gridview, xml-parsing

Right now i am trying to show the data from the xml file in android.
After the development of the project then i just run the project,my emulator is getting run but the application which i have created is not getting launch.

How to overcome this issue?

**logcat**

```
[2012-09-03 14:37:28 - GridView_test] Android Launch!
[2012-09-03 14:37:28 - GridView_test] adb is running normally.
[2012-09-03 14:37:28 - GridView_test] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-09-03 14:37:28 - GridView_test] The launch will only sync the application package on the  device!
[2012-09-03 14:37:28 - GridView_test] Performing sync
[2012-09-03 14:37:29 - GridView_test] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5556' running compatible AVD 'Android22-API-8'
[2012-09-03 14:37:29 - GridView_test] Uploading GridView_test.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
[2012-09-03 14:37:30 - GridView_test] Installing GridView_test.apk...
[2012-09-03 14:37:34 - GridView_test] Success!
[2012-09-03 14:37:34 - GridView_test] \GridView_test\bin\GridView_test.apk installed on device
[2012-09-03 14:37:34 - GridView_test] Done!
```

Thanks in advance!..

Comment: What do you have in the logcat?

Comment: @VladimirIvanov please visit my question again i have given logcat for reference

Comment: check your manifest contains   <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to change your main activity's `<intent-filter>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<application android:name="......"
android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name=".yourActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Means, you've to change your activity's `<action>` and `<category>`

Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12215555/940096) for more.